# Sending PUT request via HttpClient to Saucelabs not responding

Tags: c#, .net, rest, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I am trying to send a `PUT` request to update a job on [Saucelabs](http://saucelabs.com) via [their API](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Job+Methods#JobMethods-UpdateJob). However, the following code hangs and I am not sure why.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var sessionId = Browser.Driver.GetSessionId();
    var uri = new Uri($"https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/{Configuration.SauceUserName}/jobs/{sessionId}");
    var uriWithCred =
        new UriBuilder(uri)
        {
            UserName = $"{Configuration.SauceUserName}",
            Password = $"{Configuration.SauceAccessKey}"
        }.Uri;
    var payload = new StringContent($"{{\"name\":\"{TestMethodName}\"}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Put,
        RequestUri = uriWithCred,
        Content = payload
    };
    var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;                
}
```

The following cUrl request is successful (redacted credentials, of course).

```
curl -X PUT -s -u <username>:<access-key> 
-d "{\"name\": \"test name\"}"
https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/<username>/jobs/<job-id>
```

**Why does this request hang and what can I do to make it successful?**

For reasons unrelated to the question, I am unable to set the name of the job when setting the capabilities of the WebDriver.

Comment: Assuming it hangs on waiting for the response, have you used Fiddler (or any other tool) to compare the headers of both requests (your code vs cUrl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this request hang and what can I do to make it successful?

Most probably there is a mixing of async and blocking calls like `.Result` on the `client.SendAsync` method which can cause deadlocks or as you put it, *cause code to hang*.

Consider making the method call async all the way using `await`.

```
public async Task CallAPIAsync() {    
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
        var sessionId = Browser.Driver.GetSessionId();
        var uri = new Uri($"https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/{Configuration.SauceUserName}/jobs/{sessionId}");
        var uriWithCred =
            new UriBuilder(uri) {
                UserName = $"{Configuration.SauceUserName}",
                Password = $"{Configuration.SauceAccessKey}"
            }.Uri;
        var payload = new StringContent($"{{\"name\":\"{TestMethodName}\"}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage {
            Method = HttpMethod.Put,
            RequestUri = uriWithCred,
            Content = payload
        };
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I don't have any real experience with the async mechanisms in .NET, do you have any links or resources you recommend?

Comment: @Muttonchop, This is where I got started with async/await. The author is an authority on the topic. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx